# Dispose with using C# - full implementation

Tags: c#, dispose, using

how can you implement the Dispose method after using "using" on a MemoryStream object in a class that implements IDisposable?

```
public class ControlToByte :IDisposable
{
    public static byte[] GetByte(object control)
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        { //do something here  } 
public void Dispose()
    {
       //how do you dispose of memorystream object?
    }
```

Comment: There's no indication of any reason for ControlToByte to implement IDisposable here... you haven't shown any state within the class.

Comment: In the code you posted, the `using` will dispose `memoryStream` so you don't need a separate `Dispose()`.

Comment: I'm not advising to not dispose a `MemoryStream` (because it implements `IDisposable` by inherinting from `Stream` and thus indicates that it should be disposed when no longer in use) but as the class doesn't have any non-mananged resources disposing it doesn't really free anything up. A common misconception is to believe that the memory associated with the `MemoryStream` is freed when it is disposed but that task is left to the garbage collector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to implement `IDispose`, nor do you have to call `Dispose` explicitly. The [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block will ensure that, after completion, the `MemoryStream` will be disposed. `using` blocks actually work like `try/finally` blocks. Something like:

```
{
    System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;

    try
    {
        memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        //....your code
    }
    finally
    {
        if (memoryStream != null) //this check may be optmized away
            memoryStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

[using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that **Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs** while you are calling methods on the object. You
>   can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block
>   and then **calling Dispose in a finally block**; in fact, this is how
>   the using statement is translated by the compiler.

In your current code, you are implementing `IDisposable` on your class `ControlToByte`, This would be useful if you want to dispose resourses in `ControlToByte`. As illustrated, you don't need to implement `IDisposable` for your class.

Comment: ok, but there has to be a Dispose implemented somewhere, right? Where is it? @Habib

Comment: @MPN, no it doesn't have to. Unless you want to implement Dispose against `ControlToByte`. `MemoryStream` already has `IDisposable` implemented, and using statement will ensure that it calls `Dispose`, on MemoryStream object. You don't have to implement it yourself.

Comment: ok, thanks, one more thing: the using statement doesn't have to surround only objects created with new, right? @Habib

Comment: @MPN, not entirely sure about your question, `using` statement is used with those objects that implement `IDisposable`